# Questions about $E = \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^2+x+1)}$ and factorization in $E[t]$

Tags: ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Let $$E = \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^2+x+1)}$$

- For which $p \in \mathbb{N}$ does exist $h \in E$ s.t. $h^2 =p$ or $h^2=-p$
- Factorize $x^4-9$ into irreducible polynomials in $E[t]$, where $t$ is an unknow

now, $E$ is a field because $f:= x^2+x+1$ is a cyclotomic polynomial, hence irreducible on $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and a generic element in $E$ is $h=a+bx + (f)$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.

**About the first question** I tried this path: $h^2 = (a+bx+(f))^2 = a^2+2abx+b^2x^2 + (f) = (2ab-b^2)x+a^2-b^2 + (f)$

placing $\,\,b(2a-b)=0\,\,$ and $\,\,a^2-b^2=p$, but I couldn't get to the conclusion, any hint?

**About the second question**, I know that $$E[t] = \Bigl\{(a_0+b_0x+(f))+(a_1+b_1x+(f))t+...+(a_n+b_nx+(f))t^n \,\,|\;\;a_i+b_ix+(f)\in E, i\in\{0,...,n\}\Bigl\}$$

but I have no idea how to factorize $x^4-9$ there, any hint?

Comment: Hint: By the quadratic formula the zeros of $x^2+x+1$ are $(-1\pm i\sqrt{3})/2$. So it looks like $-3$ has a square root in $E$, doesn't it? Do you know how to prove that, for example, $\sqrt2$ and/or $\sqrt{2}$ are not elements of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$?

Comment: Should have said "$\sqrt{2}$ and/or $\sqrt{-2}$" above :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue on your idea for question 1: $b(2a-b)=0$ implies $b=0$, in which case $p=a^2$ is a perfect square. Otherwise $b=2a$ in which case $p=-3a^2$. Because $p$ is integer, $a$ has again to be integer.

For question 2 you can start factorizing in $\mathbb Q[x]$:
$$x^4-9=(x^2-3)(x^2+3)$$

Now we know from question 1 that $3$ does not have a square root in $E$, and that $-3$ has.
So there exists $\alpha\in E$ s.t. $x^2+3=(x-\alpha)(x+\alpha)$, while $x^2-3$ has to be irreducible. Thus the decomposition is:

$$x^4-9=(x^2-3)(x-\alpha)(x+\alpha)$$

If you let $\beta=x+(f)$ you get from the detail of question 1 that $\alpha=1+2\beta$.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear!